# R find replace in data frame

Tags: r, tidyr, find-replace

I tried to find an answer for this in other posts but nothing seemed to be working.

I have a data set where people answered the city they were in using a free response format. Therefore for each city, people identified in many different ways. For example, those living in Atlanta might have written "Atlanta", "atlanta", "Atlanta, GA" and so on.

There are 12 cities represented in this data set. I'm trying to clean this variable so each city is written consistently. Is there a way to do this efficiently for each city?
I've tried mutate_if and str_replace_all but can't seem to figure it out (see my code below)

```
all_data_city <- mutate_if(all_data_city, is.character, 
                str_replace_all, pattern = "Atlanta, GA",  
                replacement = "Atlanta")
```

```
all_data_city %>%
  str_replace_all(c("Atlanta, GA" & "HCA Atlanta" & "HCC Atlanta" &
                      "Suwanee" & "Suwanee, GA" & "suwanee"), = "Atlanta")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, [edit] your question and show how your dataset looks like, preferably by providing a [mcve]. For instance, `dput(head(all_data_city))`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to pass a vector of elements to be replaced, `paste` them together with `|` as pattern and replace with 'Atlanta'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
pat <- str_c(c("Atlanta, GA" , "HCA Atlanta" , "HCC Atlanta" ,
                  "Suwanee" , "Suwanee, GA" , "suwanee"), collapse = "|")
all_data_city %>%
         str_replace_all(pat, "Atlanta")
```

---

Using a reproducible example with `iris`

```
iris %>% 
   transmute(Species = str_replace_all(Species, 
           str_c(c("set", "versi"), collapse="|"), "hello")) %>% 
   pull(Species) %>% 
   unique
#[1] "helloosa"   "hellocolor" "virginica"
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions on data cleaning are difficult to answer, as answers strongly depend on the data.
Proposed solutions may work for a (small) sample dataset but may fail for a (large) production dataset.

In this case, I see two possible approaches:

- Collecting all possible ways of writing a city's name and replacing these different variants by the desired city name. This can be achieved by `str_replace()` or by *joining*. This is safe but tedious.
- Looking for a matching character string *within* the city name and replace if found.

Below is a blue print which can be extended for other uses cases. For demonstration, a data.frame with one column `city` is created:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data.frame(city = c("Atlanta, GA", "HCA Atlanta", "HCC Atlanta",
                    "Suwanee", "Suwanee, GA", "suwanee", "Atlantic City")) %>% 
  mutate(city_new = case_when(
    str_detect(city, regex("Atlanta|Suwanee", ignore_case = TRUE)) ~ "Atlanta",
    TRUE ~ as.character(city)
  )
)
```

> ```
>            city      city_new
> 1   Atlanta, GA       Atlanta
> 2   HCA Atlanta       Atlanta
> 3   HCC Atlanta       Atlanta
> 4       Suwanee       Atlanta
> 5   Suwanee, GA       Atlanta
> 6       suwanee       Atlanta
> 7 Atlantic City Atlantic City
> ```